# How to overwrite console output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have this code:**

```
print("Please wait, your question is loading...")
sleep(4)
```

**I want to add another `print()` with text, which will replace the `print()` above after `sleep(4)`.**

How to do that? I am using the latest version Python 3.9.0

Comment: Using `sys.stdout.write` can give you more control over what is written to the console. Such as, don't send a NL, then next send only CR to return cursor to beginning of same line.

Comment: @Keith. Only works in some consoles

Comment: @Tomerikoo add that as an answer. It should be the accepted one (although the question should be closed since it is a duplicate)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Why would I add it as an answer if it is already answered? This question is a duplicate and shouldn't be answered. It should be deleted or marked as a duplicate as it is already answered somewhere else

Comment: Agreed. But since it hasn't been marked duplicated, and there is an incorrect answer marked as accepted, I suggested you put in the correct answer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you print something, then to erase it, you have not other alternative else than clear the screen. In Windows use:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

And in linux call `clear` command. And then print other things.

Comment: will it clear everything or only the text I want?

Comment: It will clear everything..... There is no there way so far

Comment: @Kladeon there is... Using `'\r'`. See the link under your question

Answer (score 0):

well you could do something like this:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

print("whatever you want")
sleep(2)
 
system("cls") # if you are on linux then replace cls with clear
print("whatever you want")
```

system.clear allows you to clear everything on the console.